# swift xcode change status bar (background color)

Tags: ios, swift

In one view I am hiding the navigation bar using:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    }
```

This makes the status bar background color appear as white.
But how do I change the background color of the status bar?

Comment: I think you should change your view's or root window's background color as I suspect that your status bar is transparent.

Comment: @ozgur My status bar is red, with white text, or it used to be. But the root view has red background color and white text

Comment: @ozgur If I set the background color of the viewcontrollers root view to eg red. It looks fine. But since I have an scroll view and then scroll to the bottom it will show a red background color at the bottom as well. When you scroll to the end and keep dragging, that bounce effect will show a red color

Comment: The status bar doesn't have a *background* color any more... does it?

Comment: status bar can have only two styles, default (which is black) and light content. -  http://rshankar.com/how-to-customize-status-bar-in-ios/

Comment: @rshankar the status bar can take the navigation bars tint color. Is there no way to keep that tint color once the navigation bar is hidden?

Comment: @nhgrif It can take the navigation bars tint color. I am hiding the navigation bar for one view which results in the status bar appearing as white

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39802582/2019221

Answer (score 0):

You can have a light color and dark color for your status bar

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(.LightContent, animated: true)
```

(or)

```
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(.Default, animated: true)
```

Comment: This only makes the text / background white or black. I want to set the background color of the status bar to red

Answer (score 0):

You can change the status bar styles by setting a key "**Status Bar Style**" in the info.plist.

The following three different styles are present for status bars:-
**Status bar style - String**

1. Gray style (default)
2. Transparent black style (alpha of 0.5)
3. Opaque black style

[image]

You can also change the setting from all view controllers to view controller based status bar, by changing the following key in the info.plist:-

**View controller-based status bar appearance - Boolean**

1. Yes
2. No

[image]