# Same color for StatusBar and NavigationBar iOS

Tags: swift

I added navigationBar manualy from controls 
[image]

How to make StatusBar Backgroud color = same as navigationBar

[image]

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/39802582/5327882

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Status Bar Background Color in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802420/change-status-bar-background-color-in-swift-3)

Comment: and how to back to default when view disappear ??

Comment: Is not possible to link status with navigationBar whitout changing backgroud color of status like we do for UINavigationController ?

Answer (score 4):

**Try this code:** Tested in `Swift 3`

```
@IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black // Set any colour 
    navBar.isTranslucent = false

    navBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue", size: 16)!]

    let barView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.frame.width, height:UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height))
    barView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    view.addSubview(barView)
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {

    return .lightContent
}
```

**Updated** to clear `down voters`

[image]