# set custom color of status bar in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

On a view controller, i want to set the color of status bar black but I am not able to change it. I am using below code for this purpose.

```
 func setUpUI() {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default
    }
```

I have also added the value in info.plist

[image]

Comment: You can't set the color. However, you *can* do two things - put an image behind it and/or set the *"style"* (or find to light or dark. (And sure, you can hide it and by doing that create your own status bar - I wouldn't suggest that.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Status Bar Background Color in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802420/change-status-bar-background-color-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 4):

You just override the return value of the status bar, like this:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
   return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: You can also use the function `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` and call it when you want to change the status bar color.

Answer (score 2):

```
Use below code for swift 4 and Xcode 9.2.
```

1) In

> **info.plist** Set
>
> View controller-based status bar appearance **Key** to
>
> NO

2) In

> AppDelegate
>
> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

set Below Code

```
let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
    if statusBar.responds(to:#selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```