# Is it possible to change the font color of the status bar to a custom color?

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

I would like to set the color of the font of the status bar displaying the time and battery percentage to a custom color other than the enumerations `.default` and `.lightContent` [UIStatusBar Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistatusbarstyle).
Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set custom color of status bar in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47172368/set-custom-color-of-status-bar-in-swift)

Comment: @Carpsen90 I appreciate your concern however that question deals with the color of the bar the super view underlying the time and battery percentage. I would like to change the color of the font not the bar to a custom color other than the enumerations offered by apple `.default` and `.lightContent`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistatusbarstyle

Comment: Could you please check the answers there? AFAIK the answer to your question is no.

Comment: @Carpsen90 I appreciate your help. I have checked and as I mentioned before that question deals with setting the background color of the `UIStatusBar` which is the underlying view. I would like to change the color of the font which is contained on the StatusBar to a custom color other than `.default` and `.lightContent`.

Answer (score 0):

**For a production application I don't think it's possible**, however by means of private frameworks you can make

```
(UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! NSObject).setValue(UIColor.red, forKey: "foregroundColor")
```

Comment: This would be rejected by Apple