# Color of status bar does not change as my navigationbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, navigationbar

I bumped into an odd problem. Suddenly the color of my status bar does not change color to the same as my navigationbar in my tabbarcontroller.

[image]

I've tried setting the color of the navigationbar

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 57, green: 79, blue: 116)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```

But it just change the color of the navigationbar, not the statusbar. What am I missing?

Comment: are you sure that you're not changing navigationBar height anywhere in your code?

Comment: Yea, I'm pretty sure

Comment: FYI - you are creating your `UIColor` incorrectly. Values should be in the range 0.0 - 1.0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> [Answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39802582/9333764):

```
extension UIApplication {
    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }
}

UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = .red
```

Comment: This is unnecessary and could stop working in a future iOS update or get your app rejected by Apple for digging into the private subview structure. There are countless apps that don't need code like this to get the status bar to show the correct color.

Answer (score 0):

create navigation controller in storyboard, tie it to controller and change the color of there. If it allows your project of course..