# Change background color of status bar

Tags: ios, swift

I have a very simple web view project which just loads a website. There is a bug though, the website content is showing in the status bar if I scroll down.

[image]

I read that this is because the background color of the ViewController is set to be transparent, how can I change it to another color?

I tried it like this:

```
let color = UIColor.black;
self.view.backgroundColor = color
```

But nothing changes

Whole Code:

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // 1  The webView loads the url using an URLRequest object.
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.blizz-z.de/")!

        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))

        // 2  A refresh item is added to the toolbar which will refresh the current webpage.
        let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(
            barButtonSystemItem: .refresh,
            target: webView,
            action: #selector(webView.reload)
        )

        toolbarItems = [refresh]
        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

    }

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
        let color = UIColor.black;
        self.view.backgroundColor = color
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        title = webView.title
    }



}
```

I could just disable the status bar with the following code to fix the bug, but I try to keep it:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: If its a website which you are loading in the web view, and title bar is present in your website, then how you can change it in your IOS code? If this is the case not possible, you need to change it in your website code.

Comment: The status bar is not from my website, it is from the iPhone.

Comment: The status bar is transparent. The end. If you don't want something to show behind it, don't _put_ something behind it.

Comment: @matt, So how should I solve the problem, it is clearly a problem of iOS or Xcode. I developed the exact same app for android and everything is working fine there.

Comment: Dont set the webview as the self.view. add the webview as a child view using self.view.addSubview() and set the constraint properly to omit the top status bar. Dont forget to set the clipsToBound to true for webview.

Comment: @RatulSharker, I need more details please, screenshots would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

        let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: (URL(string: "https://www.blizz-z.de/")!)))
        view.addSubview(webView)
         UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411765, green: 0.9529411765, blue: 0.9529411765, alpha: 1)
    }


}

extension UIApplication {
    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        if responds(to: Selector("statusBar")) {
            return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to hide the status bar.

Comment: override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    } remove this line and add navigation controller behind this controller and set navigation color.

Comment: what do you want? please share any screen.

Comment: I just want to make the background color of the status bar to NOT be transparent.

Comment: Get background color from html string in website and set status bar background color :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39802582/9697632

Answer (score -1):

Make the `webView.top` constraint relative to `safeArea.top` constraint, and not the `superview.top` constraint. This allows you to make your `webView` under the status bar.

Comment: No, you could do it from the `Storyboard` by editing the top constraint of the `webView`.

Comment: The constraints are grayed out

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your storyboard file ? (try to show us your constraints)

Comment: Here WKWebview is assigned to self.view.

Comment: I don't understand how to do it, im beginner